# Tutorial for Facebook Registration Plugin

Tags: facebook, plugins, registration

I am seeking a tutorial where I can read how to use the Facebook registration plugin.

On the Facebook page of that plugin it's not clearly understandable.

Comment: The documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ is pretty clear. What didn't you understand?

Comment: how do i get the contents that are being fetched by the plugin , also how to store them to my mysql table

Comment: Well, they give you actual sample code for getting the contents of the form, in the section titled "PHP Example reading signed_request". Saving to your database should be done like you'd insert any other data.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

On this page , can you tell me how many pages will actually be needed?

According to me 2 pages:
1. The page where the iframe is to be placed
2. signed_request.php

Comment: That's correct, although you could conceivably do both on one page by looking for the `signed_request` and doing an `if() { } else { }` sort of logic.

Comment: Also, i have no idea how to insert these json fields into my database.

Can you provide a simple example? Please!

Comment: Use `json_decode()` to turn them into standard PHP variables, then do what you'd normally do with such things.

Comment: This question may be closed as Needs Clarity or Request For External Resources.